Connecting to ATT, I get OpenSSL: pending error: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
When I try to connect to AT&T with WPA Supplicant running on OpenWRT, I'm getting,
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE EAP authentication failed
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-STARTED EAP authentication started
10g-2: CTRL-EVENT-EAP-PROPOSED-METHOD vendor=0 method=13
OpenSSL: pending error: error:0A00018E:SSL routines::ca md too weak
TLS: Failed to set TLS connection parameters
EAP-TLS: Failed to initialize SSL.
10g-2: CTRL-REQ-PASSPHRASE-0:Private key passphrase needed for SSID
10g-2: EAP: Failed to initialize EAP method: vendor 0 method 13 (TLS)

How can I resolve this error?

If you're going to downvote, at least provide input..

The certificate has an md5 hash. To use that would require disabling effectively all security features. The levels are 0 through 5, and the default is 1. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_security_level.html

openssl_ciphers=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
This error is because I needed to add the line openssl_ciphers=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0 to my /etc/config/wpa_supplicant.conf,
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
eapol_version=1
ap_scan=0
fast_reauth=1
openssl_ciphers=DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=0
network={
   ...
}

